# python library to generator previous and next prime quickly

Tags: numbers, generator, primes

is there a library in Python that, given an integer, can generate the previous and the next closest prime number. I know there are some that will give me the next prime number, but I was hoping there was one that also did the previous prime.

Comment: Why not have a look at the next prime generator and re-engineer it to find the previous prime?  Hint: try `n - 2` instead of `n + 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy's ntheory (Number Theory) class will do this.

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html

```
sympy.ntheory.generate.nextprime(n)
sympy.ntheory.generate.prevprime(n)
```

It is decent, though not the fastest if you include non-Python libraries (10x slower than Pari/GP, 20-40x slower than Perl/ntheory).  That probably does not matter to most users who aren't either doing vast numbers of calls or using it with 1000+ digit inputs.